# How can I optimize user authentification?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore, session-variables

I'm using Node.js Google App Engine with Firestore.
To get information from my database I've planned to use a custom API that uses session variable as an authenfication process, which from my point of view improves security (maybe a total misunderstanding)

Only problem is if user looses his permission level (access revoked to services for example)
at any time, user still can have full access to his old rights until the session is lost.

One workaround though would be to gain access before each api calls to his permission level (the one that is updated in realtime in Firestore) and then proceed or not.

Can't find a better solution, but this solution needs two calls to firestore (1 read for user's permission level and 1 read or write to read or write desired data) . Any other solutions? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here.  Especially the part where you state that "this solution multiply by two the number of reads". Could you edit the question to explain in more detail?

Comment: @dougstevenson Thank you for your comment. I've just added a short explanation. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure about this but... maybe you could implement some [Security rules](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/get-started) for this... and this would let you know if the user is still able to get information (based on the rules that you set for it) It seems like a possible solution.

Comment: @LuisManuel Thank you I'll have a deeper look into it. one thing though is that I don't authenticatte via firebase so I don't know if that's still possible. Still I was looking for a more general workaround even without using firestore I'm stuck with that problem

Comment: @DougStevenson Did you had a better understanding. I'm sorry I was on my mobile phone when editing the post which makes it harder. When I said twice I meant that every api call needs to check for permisssion level. So that means that I I want to get for example 10 times a list of people via the API, Ill nned to do 20 reads in total